# Having an NSManagedObject property of type of another NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, entity, nsmanagedobject, datamodel

I looked over the SO, but strangely didn't find similar question.
So the question is: If i have an entity called A and an entity called B, can B object have a property of type A? NOT relationship, but a property. I surely can use relationship as a property, but in my case i need an A object to have a property with type of A object. for example
Entity called Human. And a property called child which is a Human too.

```
Human* parent=[Nsentity....bla bla
Human* child=parent.child;
```

Is there a way to do this not using transformable properties? I tried non-inverse relationship to self, but it rises a warning, and im like afraid that its gonna be a mess after all. cos in my case "parent" and "child" might be exactly the same object. so parent.child might be equal to parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no prevention for "self" relationships.

An entity `A` may have a relation (one-to-one or one-to-many) with entity `A` or any of its descendants (or any other entity for that matter).

Define `A` like so (for one-to-one relationship):
parent (reltionship with inverse `A`->`child`)
child (relationship with inverse `A`->`parent`)

You probably don't want this to be a property as CoreData will not maintain it as part of the object graph (cascade rules and such).

Comment: so i should just ignore the warning about no inverse ?

Comment: or just add the inverse